# update array state in flux-like

Tags: javascript, redux, vuex, flux

When I use flux-like like Vuex or Redux. I have a question about list state update.

I have list data in flux state.

```
// state.js 

{
  itemById: {},
}
```

And I have item's id array in list component.

```
// listComponent.js

{
  data: {
    itemIds: [],
    items: data.itemIds.map(id => state.itemById[id]),
  };
}
```

Now I add an item in other component.

```
// otherComponent.js

  addItem(newItem) {
    store.dispatch(newItem);
  }
```

Then the `itemById` state have the `newItem`, but the `itemIds` don't have the `newItem`'s id.

if move the `itemIds` to state. When the `listComponent` destroy and recreat, `itemIds` still exist, but I don't want this.

What should I do to update `itemIds` simply?

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that you have 2 copies of the same data: one in state and one in `data` of `listComponent`. Assuming `listComponent`'s data is initiated from state's data, for every update in state, you need to catch and update local component's data to match them. Destroying and recreating the component does not directly update local data, and it's not recommended to recreate the whole component just for the local data, since it beats the purpose of component life cycle.

Flux aside, one of the reasons people use state management tool like redux or vuex is because of single source of truth - there should be one copy of global state from which any component can read. To fix your code, one solution is to move `itemIds` and `items` from `data` to `computed` and directly take them from state.

```
computed: {
    itemIds() {
        return Object.keys(state.itemByIds);
    },
    items() {
        return Object.values(state.itemByIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my question well. The reason I have 2 copies is that I use the different parts of the same items in two component such as `listComponent1` `listComponent2`, but I can't filter item by itself. So I create different `itemIds` in different component.

Comment: @Senasiko even so, it doesn't mean that you should create copy of original state - you have to watch the global state, e.g. length of state `items` after adding new one, to let `listComponent` detect updates on global state and update its own `itemIds` accordingly, and with `itemIds` you still can get computed `items` correctly, thus reduce a part of the copy. But then again, what you should strike for is a way to filter and computed the correct `itemIds` and `items`.

Comment: @Senasiko if you're still stuck with filtering logic, you can update your question or create a new one - I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @blaz answer, If you are using redux, in your `listComponent.js` you must use the `connect` function from `react-redux` lib. It will give the possibility to load the data from your state and inject it as props in your component.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const itemIds = Object.keys(state.itemById);
  const items = Object.values(state.itemById);
  return { itemIds, items };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListComponent);
```